# Specifying the size of svg from standalone Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, size

I'm currently using Tikz together with the `standalone` package to generate vector graphics, that I convert from pdf to svg using `pdf2sg`.

To draw circuits I'm using `circuitikz`, but the question is about sizing Tikz figures in general. For reference, this is how my figures look:

```latex
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 2) to [battery1] (0, 0);
    \draw (0, 2) to[R, l=$R_\mathrm{1}$] (3, 2);
    \draw (3, 2) to[D, l=$D_\mathrm{1}$] (3, 0);
    \draw (3, 0) -- (0, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

When I open up the resulting .svg file, the dimensions are set to `width="127.815pt"` and `height="77.858pt"`

Is there an option within Tex to specify the size of the figure I'm creating with Tikz?

Edit: Changed the word from "determine" to "specify" to clarify my intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `adjustbox` to adjust the size of anything, including `tikzpicture`s ans `circuitikz`.

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=3cm,height=2cm}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 2) to [battery1] (0, 0);
    \draw (0, 2) to[R, l=$R_\mathrm{1}$] (3, 2);
    \draw (3, 2) to[D, l=$D_\mathrm{1}$] (3, 0);
    \draw (3, 0) -- (0, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: Compiling

```
\documentclass[convert = false]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at end picture={
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.north east)-(current bounding box.south
west)$) in \pgfextra{\message{x dimension=\x1, y dimension=\y1^^J}};}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0, 2) to [battery1] (0, 0);
    \draw (0, 2) to[R, l=$R_\mathrm{1}$] (3, 2);
    \draw (3, 2) to[D, l=$D_\mathrm{1}$] (3, 0);
    \draw (3, 0) -- (0, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

yields the message

> x dimension=124.65718pt, y dimension=76.92181pt

Comment: Hi, I think I should've used a different phrasing. Is it possible to _specify_ what dimensions I want the final figure to have? As in, can I set a x and y value that Tikz will then try to follow? Ultimately, I would like be able to scale up the svg by some factor.

Comment: @RasmusKällqvist You can use the adjustbox package to achieve this, see my update.

Comment: @SchrödingersCat That package did the trick! The background to the question was that I wanted to use this in web layouting, so this helps tremendously.